# Significance Of % sign in Response.write()

Tags: vbscript

```
<%response.write("This is my first VBScript!")%>
```

What is the significance of % sign in this statement? What is the use of it?
Please tell me. I am getting Confuse ..

Comment: I'm confused, too. I don't even see it!

Comment: Can you give an example? Is it being passed like an argument (i.e. a formatting symbol), or with a number (modulus)?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Post an example of what you mean.

Comment: The code was there, just wasn't being shown since it wasn't marked as a code sample. @user3691696, you can highlight code by selecting it, then clicking the `{ }` button (or pressing Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 1):

In "Classic ASP" (not ASP.NET)  `<%` means "Start of server-side processing block", which means the server's script parser will be invoked and will execute anything that follows that symbol up until it encounters a matching `%>` symbol.

Classic ASP also supports `<script runat="server" language="VBScript">` as an alternative, which as a bonus lets you mix server-side JScript and VBScript in the same page (by setting the `language` attribute accordingly).

The choice of `<%` is rather arbitrary, you'll have to ask the original designer of ASP's syntax (if you can find them), however it's equivalent to PHP's `<?php`. JSP also has similar syntax.

In ASP.NET Web Forms (and ASP.NET MVC when using the Web Forms view-engine) the semantics are different but the practical use is the same: `<%` denotes the end of literal output in the page's `Render` function and so means the beginning of code to be executed, except that this all happens **within** the implementation of the `Render` function so you cannot define new functions/methods or types/classes, for that you must use `<script runat="server">` (again, hold-over syntax from Classic ASP but with different semantics).

You can see this in practice by opening the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder on your computer and looking at the generated `.cs` files that correspond to each `.aspx` file.